# Django database connection with postgis automatically shutdown after serval time

Tags: python, django, postgresql, gis, postgis

My database automatically shuts down after a few hours. I'm using PostgreSQL 14 with Django 4.2.4,In django i am getting connection refused error ,When i  amdcheckfor postgress status it and here's my database configuration in settings.py and PostgreSQL logs, I see the following logs:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
        'NAME': 'fight-db',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'gsdgfwtdtfw',
        'HOST': '192.**********',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

> In the PostgreSQL logs, I see the following logs:
>
> 2023-09-21 21:48:11.208 UTC [15283] LOG: received fast shutdown request
>
> 2023-09-21 21:48:11.222 UTC [15283] LOG: aborting any active transactions
>
> 2023-09-21 21:48:11.264 UTC [15283] LOG: background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 15290) exited

Answer (score 0):

According to the log you provided, PostgreSQL was presented with a "fast shutdown request" and cancelled any open transactions. This behavior shows that PostgreSQL is being shut down or restarted by a source outside of your Django application.

Your Django configuration does not appear to be the cause of the PostgreSQL shutdown problem you're having. For potential causes, examine PostgreSQL's setup, server resources, outside scripts, and system monitoring. Maintain the most recent versions of Django and PostgreSQL, and keep an eye on how your application's code handles database connections. Consider asking a system administrator or PostgreSQL specialist for help if the issue doesn't go away.